# How to ignore unmapped fields in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need help to setup the Elastich search properly.

I installed `Elasticpress` in my wordpress and set the Elastic server at Google cloud using `bitnami`. My theme default search has its own search and I get this error in `Elasticpress` debug mode:

```
No mapping found for [meta._iwj_featured_date.l­ong]
```

in order to sort on I found the below solution from [this guide:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_f%C2%ADields)

```
GET /_search
{
    "sort" : [
        { "price" : {"missing" : "_last"} }
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "product" : "chocolate" }
    }
}
```

But where I need to put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden Meta (custom fields) are fields that start with _ (underscore).
Elasticpress will not map them by default. To bypass this there's a filter.
Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'ep_prepare_meta_allowed_protected_keys', function( $protected_keys ) {
    $protected_keys[] = '_iwj_featured_date';
    return $protected_keys;
} );
```

Then re-index the site from elasticpress interface.
Your meta will be mapped. Now you can sort by it.